# Python OpenCV namedWindow and imshow freeze

Tags: python, opencv, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I try to view a subscribed image via cv2.imshow() like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, rospy, traceback, cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

window_name = 'detection'


class imShow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/image_raw', Image, self.callback)

    def callback(self, data):
        try:
            cv_img = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
        except CvBridgeError as exc:
            print('###CVBridgeError###')
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            print(exc)
        cv2.imshow(window_name, cv_img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


def main(args):
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
    ims = imShow()
    rospy.init_node('imshow', anonymous=True)

    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print('Shutting down...')
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

But this way the namedWindows shows up at the first call and does'nt update any more and freezes.

Because I want to add some trackbars to adjust values, which will be processed in the callback function, I want to declare and initialize the window and the trackbars outside of the class. I had it working with doing it inside of the callback function, but after a few seconds the node crashed with the error "Process finished with exit code 139". I thought the reason for this may have been a memory overflow because the window and the trackbars were created again and again with each call of the callback function.

So does anybody have an idea how to handle this?

Thanks and regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257440/python-opencv-namedwindow-and-imshow-freeze/) by [UllusParvus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29586/ullusparvus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-03-20**:
You have some indentation issues in your try-except block, but maybe that is just a copy-paste error. Have you verified that an image is actually being published on the `/camera/rgb/image_raw` topic? If no images are published your callback will never run and you'll never see an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The intendation issue was really just a copy-paste error, I corrected it.
I've also verified that the image is actually being published on this topic. When I leave out the line with `cv2.namedWindow(window_name)`, the image is properly shown in a OpenCV-Window, caused by the line `cv2.imshow(window_name, cv_img)`.
But like I said, I want to declare and initialize the namedWindow outside of the callback function to prevent the above mentioned error, which may be an overflow caused by the recursive call of the callback function.

**Updated Answer**

Here is how it works for me. I can now close the cv2 windows with the Escape-Button. I've also added trackbars to update image detection parameters during runtime, maybe that is also helpful for somebody.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, rospy, traceback, math, cv2, numpy as np, std_msgs.msg
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError


class objectDetection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/image_rect_color', Image, self.callback)
        self.orig_img = None
        self.params = None

    def callback(self, data):
        self.params = self.getTrackbarParams()
        try:
            cv_img = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(frame, "bgr8")
        except CvBridgeError as exc:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        if 'cv_img' in locals():
            self.orig_img = cv_img

    def getTrackbarParams(self):
        return [cv2.getTrackbarPos('Param', 'Parameter-Trackbars')]


def showImages(obj):
    if obj.orig_img is not None:
        cv2.imshow('Original', obj.orig_img)

def handleTrackbarChanges(obj):
    params = obj.getTrackbarParams()

def trackbar_callback(x):
    pass

def createWindowsAndTrackbars():     
    cv2.namedWindow('Parameter-Trackbars')
    cv2.namedWindow('Original')

    cv2.createTrackbar('Param', 'Parameter-Trackbars', 0, 179, trackbar_callback)
    # some more stuff

def main(args):
    createWindowsAndTrackbars()
    od = objectDetection()
    rospy.init_node('objectdetection', anonymous=True)

    while (1):
        [...]
        cv2.imshow('Parameter-Trackbars', cv2.cvtColor(trackbar_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR))
        showImages(od)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
        
        handleTrackbarChanges(od)

        try:
            rospy.spin()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Shutting down...')
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

---

Originally posted by [UllusParvus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29586/ullusparvus/) with karma: 56 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-20**:
If this is just showing the first image and then freezing, maybe you should remove the `cv2.waitKey()` ?

**Comment by [UllusParvus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29586/ullusparvus/) on 2017-03-21**:
I have to correct, it s not showing the first image, the window is freezing instantly after popping up with nothing in it.
Thanks for the hint, but when removing the `cv2.waitKey()`, it also freezes and also does not work any more when removing the line `cv2.namedWindow(window_name)`

**Comment by [UllusParvus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29586/ullusparvus/) on 2017-03-21**:
Got it, I'll post a shorted code snippet later

**Comment by [sunbuny](https://answers.ros.org/users/31181/sunbuny/) on 2017-07-13**:
I am facing the same problem now.Can you tell me how to fix the problem. Thank you

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-09**:
Same problem. Unless I do the namedWindow() call in a ROS thread (Here callback of a subscriber) the whole program freezes.

**Comment by [UllusParvus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29586/ullusparvus/) on 2017-10-09**:
Hi guys,

sorry for let you waiting such a long time. See my updated answer above. Hope this will help you.

**Comment by [lennonwoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32943/lennonwoo/) on 2017-12-11**:
+1 The ui update shoudn't be updated in non main thread. We could put the image processing logic in non main thread, then use Queue to store the processed image for main thrad's cv.imshow() or something else.